# Is there a verb form of "intermission"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb form of the noun "intermission"?  I know that many nouns have a verb form, but does this word have one, or is it only a noun?

Comment: Try to find 'intermit' in a dictionary. It exists, but I've never seen or heard it used.

Comment: Can you give a sample sentence. It might be used in different ways, for instance intransitively "The play will _ at 9.30" or transitively "He _ the meeting to allow for refreshments". It also might vary depending on whether it was in a play, a meeting, a career, or something else, short or long.

Answer (score 4):

The verb form is "intermit".

> **intermit, v.1**
>
> 1 a. transitive. To leave off, give over, discontinue (an action, practice, etc.) for a time; to suspend.
>
> 2 a. intr. To cease or stop for a time (†const. from, or inf.); to be intermittent.
>
> b. spec. in Path. of a fever (pain, etc.) or of the pulse.

Source: [The OED](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00119350) - There are also a few obsolete definitions which I have left out here.

Although the OED says the verb is in current use, a search in [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intermit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows it to be very rare, at least since the beginning of the last century. From what I can tell, modern usage seems to be limited to some technical publications, I assume as some kind of technical jargon.

It might be better instead to use some of those other verbs in the definitions given above, depending on context of course.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you're looking to describe specifically an intermission (the time between acts in a play or performance), you can use a construction like 'took an intermission' to describe it's occurrence.